# WindowsAzure.MobileServiceSqliteStore is undefined

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, azure

I am trying to use the Azure mobile apps cordova plugin to implement offline sync on my app (following the instructions over here https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client)

This is my code:

```
  var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('http://historyprep.azurewebsites.net');
  var store = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceSqliteStore('local.db');
```

This is my error (happens both on Ripple and on actual device)

```
ionic.bundle.js:25642 TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined
  at new MobileServiceSqliteStore (MobileServices.Cordova.js:46542)
```

All I had did was install the plugin `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ms-azure-mobile-apps`. Do I need to install anything else?

Answer (score 0):

According the description in the source code at https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/blob/master/sdk/src/Platforms/cordova/MobileServiceSqliteStore.js#L7:

> This uses the https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-sqlite-storage Cordova plugin.

Unfortunately, it doesn't support browser target, please refer to the same issue on GitHub at https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/issues/225.

Please try to test in devices or emulators.

## update:

I test the following code snippet in my test project, and run on my device:

```
    var store = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceSqliteStore('store.db');
    store.defineTable({
        name: 'todoitem',
        columnDefinitions: {
            id: 'string',
            text: 'string',
            deleted: 'boolean',
            complete: 'boolean'
        }
    });
    var syncContext = client.getSyncContext();
    syncContext.initialize(store);
    var table = client.getSyncTable('todoitem');
    syncContext.push();
```

Which seems to work fine, and I get the following logs:
[image]

Comment: I tried testing it on my device, but the same issue occurred.

Comment: What error message you get on your side? It seems to work fine on my side. Please see my update logs.